# Maintenance Level no longer auto-populate when adding new Case

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We have recently migrated from CRM 2013 to CRM 2015 and notice the 'Maintenance Level' no longer auto-populates when selecting an account/business field in a new case. This is the Case:Information form not the new Case Form. The account field clearly shows an `onchange` event to update maintenance level to match the service level in the function call.
 
[image]

Maintenance Level Properties

[image]

```
function setMaintLevelFromAccount(){

if (SDK.REST){

    // only set if not already populated.

    var custID = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").getValue();

    var maintLevel = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("contractservicelevelcode").getValue();



    // if customer is populated and maint level is blank, default maint level from account

    if (custID != null){

        var odataOptions = "";

            //odataOptions = "$select=Name,PriceLevelId&$filter=Name eq '" + custID. + "' and StateCode/Value eq 0";

            odataOptions = "$select=am_servicelevel&$filter=AccountId eq guid'" + custID[0].id + "'";

        try {

            SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("Account", odataOptions, 

                function (data){

                    // if zero results and had name, try running with no name to get the latest.. 

                    if (data.length > 0){

                        var maint = data[0].am_servicelevel.Value;



                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("contractservicelevelcode").setValue(maint);



                    }

                    else {

                         Xrm.Page.getAttribute("contractservicelevelcode").setValue(null);

                    }

                }, 

                function (error){

                    // alert ("error: " + error.message);

                }, 

                function (complete){

            });

        }

        catch (err) {



        }

    }

  }
}
```

Is this a known issue? We did apply 0.1 update to resolve the issue with Activities Showing Offline but no further updates have been applied yet.

Comment: How does your _setMaintLevelFromAccount_ function look?

Comment: Adding setMaintLevelFromAccount function above.

Comment: remove the try catch (FYI: empty catch = bad code) and see if any error pops up

Comment: Alex, removing try/catch produces this error: https://community.dynamics.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/117/mainte3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getServerUrl()` had been deprecated. Changing to `getClientUrl()` in js resolves the issue.